Trouble getting log function to work in a custom function for Google sheets
Ok the error says:

#ERROR! TypeError: Math.Log is not a function (Line 11)

Here is the code now:
/**
 * Find Lot Midpoint value. (Start, End, Total, Slope)
 * @param {number} Start The Start QTY of lot.
 * @param {number} Last The Finish QTY of lot.
 * @param {number} Total The Total QTY of lot.
 * @param {number} Slope The Slope of the Curve.
 * @return The calculated cost change.
 * @customfunction 
 */
function Midpoint(Start, End, Total, Slope) {
  return (((1 / (1 + (Math.Log(Slope) / Math.Log(2)))) * ((Last + 0.5) ** (1 + (Math.Log(Slope) / Math.Log(2))) - (First - 0.5) ** (1 + (Math.Log(Slope) / Math.Log(2))))) / Total) ** (1 / (Math.Log(Slope) / Math.Log(2)));
}


Please post your full relevant code and specify what your output errors are whenever something "isn't working".

In your code, what is qty? Have you declared it?

You are correct I have it defined as total not QTY

well I fixed that and still getting an error. I'm adding the code as it is now to the bottom of my question and Ill copy the error

Please do not ask more than one question per post. And please, try to work things out by yourself before asking for help; for instance, by  reading the documentation: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/log.

Ok so, to summarise:

to exponentiate, type a**b;
to compute a natural logarithm, type Math.log;
initialise variables before using them in an expression;
JavaScript is case-sensitive, so Math.log is not the same as Math.Log, which indeed is not a function.

